# angular material sidenav not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to make a side nav. I have seen a tutorial online and followed it. it seems everything I did is right but it's not working.

I will really appreciate if you help me out. thanks in advance

the Codes

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout, $mdSidenav) {

  $scope.openSideNavPanel = function() {
      $mdSidenav('left').open();
  };
  $scope.closeSideNavPanel = function() {
      $mdSidenav('left').close();
  };
```

});

Html:

```
<md-toolbar>
    <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Side Panel" ng-click="openSideNavPanel()">
        <md-tooltip>Side Panel</md-tooltip>
        <md-icon class="md-default-theme" class="material-icons">&#xE5D2;</md-icon>
    </md-button>
</md-toolbar>

<md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" md-component-id="left">
    <md-toolbar layout="row">
     <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <h2>
          <span>Side Panel</span>
        </h2>
        <span flex></span>
        <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Close Side Panel" ng-click="closeSideNavPanel()">
          <md-tooltip>Close Side Panel</md-tooltip>
          <md-icon class="md-default-theme" class="material-icons">&#xE5CD;</md-icon>
        </md-button>
       </div>
    </md-toolbar>
    <md-content layout-padding="">
      Side navigation Panel
    </md-content>
</md-sidenav>

<md-content flex layout-padding>



    <div class="container">
    <div ng-view=""></div>
    </div>


  </div>

</md-content>
```

more info:
I am using yeoman angular generator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Answer. Everything Above is right Only an extra controller supposed to be written.

Since I am using Angular Yeoman Generator, and I was writing the Code for the Controller in MainCtrl , where MainCtrl is responsible for the View main.html only not the INDEX.html

Therefore Wrote *a new Controller* only for the index and put the about code under a div, like this

```
<div ng-controller="indexController">
       all abouve html code
  </div>
```

and it worked